# How to see requests in Sinatra?

Tags: sinatra, rack

I used to be able see http requests made for sinatra in the window I started my sinantra application from.

I think that after sinatra upgrade I cannot see them any more and I don't know how to make it so. I don't need to log them into a file.

`set :logging, true` didn't help

- ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [i386-mingw32]
- rack (1.4.0)
- rack-protection (1.2.0)
- sinatra (1.3.2)
- sinatra-advanced-routes (0.5.1)
- sinatra-reloader (0.5.0)
- sinatra-sugar (0.5.1)

Comment: could also be rack related. I saw it too after I updated both. Maybe you add that tag as well?

Comment: Bug introduced in Sinatra 1.3.2: https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/issues/454 (workaround in issue).

Comment: @matt can you create an answer from from your comment? To be honest I didn't get how the workaround works. All I use is one rb file with basically no sinatra settings in it. Could you elaborate on the workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [bug introduced in Sinatra 1.3.2](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/issues/454). The [commit that introduced it](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/commit/bf3ad8c40ae20d6358abab16c429d502bb60d49d) was intented to fix [another bug where the logging was being done *twice* in certain circumstances](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/issues/380), but obviously isn't quite right.

This request logging is done by using the `Rack::CommonLogger` middleware component, which is now only added in certain cases. The fix/workaround is to simply add it yourself. Add

```
use Rack::CommonLogger
```

to the top of your application file (after requiring Sinatra). Note that you might end up with the original problem of seeing requests logged twice in some situations (e.g. if your deployment setup is different from your development setup).

Comment: You're right. Something appears twice. Better twice than none :-) Thank you for the workaround.